# How do I only parse the timestamp from a string

Tags: python, timestamp

I am trying to parse only the timestamp from a specific line in a log file using python. This is the line from the file:

> Mar 29 06:12:42 10.11.100.22 [info.events] [WARNING] 10.11.100.22:
>   event, 1234

How do I only get the timestamp from this? This is the code I am using at the minute, which finds the line from the file which has the word 'WARNING' in it, and then gets the timestamp.

```
def is_Warning(self,line):
    if line.find("WARNING") >= 0:
        ts = time.strptime(line, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
        print "==================== %s" % ts
```

When I run this I get a 'ValueError: unconverted data remains: 10.11.100.22 [info.events] [WARNING] 10.11.100.22: event, 1234'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex.

```
import re

...

def is_warning(self,line):
    if line.find("WARNING") >= 0:
        date = re.match(r"[A-Za-z]{3} \d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}",line).group()
        ts = time.strptime(date, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
        print("===================== %s" % ts
```

Note that `time` is a really old module. You should use `datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format).time()` if you need to get JUST a time.

Answer (score 1):

The strptime should match the entire string and not just the beginning. Since you know the line's length, you can do this:

```
    ts = time.strptime(line[:15].strip(), "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
```

The [:15] method will only return the first 15 characters from the string, which are the only characters you need.

Comment: This works so long as "day" is a zero-filled value. If March 3rd is `"Mar 3 06:12:42 "` then the trailing space will break it. You can do `line[:15].strip()` though and it would be faster than my answer by far!

Comment: You are correct of course, I'll change it. Thanks :)